# cannot be initialized by a non-constant expression when being declared when using boost::assign::list_of

Tags: c++, boost, c++98

I am attempting to use `boost::assign::list_of()` to declare a static set in a class.

`MyClass.h`

```
class MyClass
{
    public:
        static std::set<std::string> & formats_set();
    private:
        static const std::set<std::string> formats_;
}
```

`MyClass.cpp`

```
const std::set<std::string> MyClass::formats_ = boost::assign::list_of(
    "Format1"
   ,"Format2"
   ,"Format3");
```

However - when I try to compile I am getting the error
`‘MyClass::formats_’ cannot be initialized by a non-constant expression when being declared`

Is there any way to get around this?
Thanks!

Comment: I guess you're bound to use c++98?

Comment: You are correct :/

Comment: If the answer below satisfies you, click the green checkmark just right of the answer's score.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now let's try it with the correct syntax:

```
#include <string>
#include <set>
#include <boost/assign/list_of.hpp> // for 'list_of()'

class MyClass
{
    public:
        static std::set<std::string> & formats_set();
    private:
        static const std::set<std::string> formats_;
};

const std::set<std::string> MyClass::formats_ = boost::assign::list_of
   ("Format1")
   ("Format2")
   ("Format3");
```

Comment: You beat me up by seconds :/ live : http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a0d235afcaa211ba (note: `<>` are unnecessary)

Comment: @YSC Thank you. Will remove them. It's been a long time since I had to use this excellent library.